# Is adding an Enum value a breaking change for GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

According to the [GraphQL Best Practices](http://graphql.org/learn/best-practices/#versioning), a GraphQL service should follow the "common practice of always avoiding breaking changes and serving a versionless API."

Is adding a value to an Enum considered a breaking change that should be avoided if following the Best Practices?

To illustrate this, let's say that the schema has this enum:

```
enum Episode {
  NEWHOPE
  EMPIRE
  JEDI
}
```

Is it bad practice to evolve the enum to be this sometime in the future:

```
enum Episode {
  NEWHOPE
  EMPIRE
  JEDI
  FORCEAWAKENS
  ROGUEONE
}
```

Comment: This particular example is not very good, because the schema is clearly poorly designed: there should be an episode entity and references to instances should be returned as IDs (or URIs). I posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596764/does-graphql-provide-an-alternative-to-enum-fields-such-as-bit-fields), taking as a given that adding a new eum value is a change that breaks clients.

Comment: @John I disagree. Regardless of how you would have designed your schema, this particular example fulfills its only purpose, which is to clearly illustrate the question that is being asked. The data that is being represented is not the point. Also worth noting is that this particular example is the example enum that the GraphQL docs use: http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#enumeration-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Adding a value to an enum is considered a "potentially dangerous change".

According to the spec (http://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Validation.Type-system-evolution)

> Any change that can cause a previously valid request to become invalid is considered a breaking change.

I tried to find a definitive list of breaking changes and it was more difficult than I expected. It appears that there is both a concept of "breaking changes" and of "dangerous changes" in graphql-js cooresponding to two functions `findBreakingChanges` and `findDangerousChanges`. `findDangerousChanges` was recommended to be added by this PR: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/701#issuecomment-277851631 because while some changes don't meet the definition of "breaking" according the the spec they are still "potentially dangerous". According the code adding a value to an enum is considered a "potentially dangerous change":
https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/40ff40a21c710372330e65f0fb58f13c2df92a77/src/utilities/findBreakingChanges.ts#L37-L63

- findBreakingChanges - https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/a24a9f35b876bdd0d5050eca34d3020bd0db9a29/src/utilities/findBreakingChanges.ts#L79)
- findDangerousChanges - https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/a24a9f35b876bdd0d5050eca34d3020bd0db9a29/src/utilities/findBreakingChanges.ts#L93

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort into this! I know this is an old question, but it finally feels like it has a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 6):

Specifically, *breaking changes* are changes to schema structure that would cause already-written queries to fail. I couldn't find an exhaustive list online, but here are few example breaking changes:

- Removing a field from an Object type (queries which used that field would become invalid)
- Adding a required argument to a field (queries which used the field *without* that argument would become invalid)
- Changing the return type of a field when the new type is not a supertype of the old type (eg, changing from `Int` to `String`, clients which used that field may have type errors from the new response).

It's possible that a new enum value could break a client (if it didn't have code to handle the new case, it may have a runtime error), but I think that's a client *design* issue, but not a breaking change to the schema!

Comment: playing devil's advocate: one of the benefits of enums is that they "[Validate that any arguments of this type are one of the allowed values](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#enumeration-types)". How can a client know what is allowed if it becomes an arbitrary list that can grow? I know the [Apollo iOS Client](http://dev.apollodata.com/ios/) will treat any response with unknown Enum values as an error. I can't think of much else you can do in that situation. Would you expect the client to handle the response differently than that?

Comment: The first point (argument values are one of the enum values) holds true if you add to an enum: A, B, and C are still valid inputs if you add D to the enum. 

As for the second point, the alternative is to design the client with a fallback case for when a new enum value appears. I'm not sure which is better!

Comment: Also, changing a non-null field to nullable

Comment: FWIW, I believe that Apollo iOS client is now designed with a fallback case as suggested in the comment above.